# CSS Underflow fix

Tags: css, overflow, underflow

I'm wondering if there are any underflow fixes for css? The initial problem was an overflow which is easily fixed but has now become an underflow problem.I have set a specific height value but it just seems to ignore this and instead resizes to suit the contents.

I appreciate any help and ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: More info is needed to be able to help here. Which browser are you using? Can you give an example of the code?, etc

Comment: Have you tries overflow: hidden and set the height to some pixel value together and even issue is still there?
If yes, Please post your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

min-height will work on some browsers, but not (surprise surprise) IE.

Here's a hack for IE6
http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/

There's a multitude of ways of fixing this, it depends which one you prefer.

Comment: Yeah, IE6 actually treats 'height' as 'min-height'. Annoying, to say the least.